# Source for a particular proof of the spectral theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, spectral-theory, compact-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Consider the following ''spectral decomposition'' for self-adjoint compact operators:

> If $T\neq 0$ is a self-adjoint compact operator on a Hilbert space $H$, then there exists
>   a sequence $\{\lambda_i\}$ of eigenvectors of $T$ (not necessarily finite) and an ortonormal sequence $\{x_i\}$ in $H$ such that each $x_i$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_i$ and
>   $$T(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i\langle x,x_i\rangle x_i,\quad\forall \ x\in H.$$

I have some notes with a proof which starts as follow:

> Since $T\neq 0$ is a self-adjoint compact operator, there exist $\lambda_1\in \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ and $x_1\in H$ such that
>   $$T(x_1)=\lambda_1 x_1,\qquad |\lambda_1|=\|T\|,\qquad \|x_1\|=1.$$
>   Define $H_1=\operatorname{span}\{x_1\}$. Note that
>   \begin{align*}
> x\in H_1^\perp\quad&\Rightarrow\quad\langle x,y\rangle=0,&&\forall \ y\in H_1\\
> &\Rightarrow\quad\langle x,Tz\rangle=0,&&\forall \ z\in H_1\\
> &\Rightarrow\quad\langle Tx,z\rangle=0,&&\forall \ z\in H_1\\
> &\Rightarrow\quad Tx\in H_1^\perp
> \end{align*}
>   and thus $T(H_1^\perp)\subset H_1^\perp$. Therefore, $T_1:=T|_{H_1^\perp}$ is self-adjoint compact operator on $H_1^\perp$.
>   If $T_1\neq 0$, there exist (as before) $\lambda_2\in \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ and $x_2\in H_1^\perp$ such that
>   $$T(x_2)=\lambda_2 x_2,\qquad |\lambda_2|=\|T_1\|,\qquad \|x_2\|=1.$$
>   Define $H_2=\operatorname{span}\{x_1,x_2\}$. As before, $T(H_2^\perp)\subset H_2^\perp$ and we define $T_2:T|_{H_2^\perp}$.
>
> By continuing this argument, we obtain a sequence $\{\lambda_i\}\subset\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ and a sequence $\{x_i\}\subset H$ such that
>   $$T(x_i)=\lambda_i x_i,\qquad |\lambda_i|=\|T_i\|\leq \|T_{i-1}\|=|\lambda_{i-1}|.$$
>   $\vdots$

**Does anyone know any book which presents this argument? Here, "this argument" means that the desired sequences are obtained by using the spaces
$$\operatorname{span}\{x_1\}^\perp,\quad \operatorname{span}\{x_1,x_2\}^\perp,\quad...$$**

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Conway's "A Course in Functional Analysis" presents this argument in the chapter about compact operators.

Comment: @el_tenedor Conway applies a similar argument. However, he uses 
$${\ker(T-\lambda_1)}^\perp,\quad \Big(\ker(T-\lambda_1)\oplus \ker(T-\lambda_2)\Big)^\perp,\quad\cdots$$